# Real Analysis: Proving the existence of a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is a question from my real analysis textbook -

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $s_n:=\sup\{x_k:k\geq n\}$ and $S:=\inf \{s_n\}$. Show that there exists a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $S$.

So, my first thought was that since $s_{n+1}\geq s_n$, it is a nonincreasing sequence and since $(x_n)$ is bounded, from monotone convergence theorem the sequence $s_n$ must converge to its infinum which is $S$. But the question asks to prove that there exists a subsequence of **$x_n$** that converges to $S$. I do not have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $m\in\Bbb N$. Since $S+\frac1m>S=\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}s_n$, there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that$$S\leqslant s_n<S+\frac1m.\tag1$$And, since $s_n=\sup_{k\geqslant n}x_k$, you can deduce from $(1)$ that there is some $n_m\in\{n,n+1,n+2,\cdots\}$ such that $S\leqslant x_{n_m}<S+\frac1m$. So, $\lim_{m\to\infty}x_{n_m}=S$.

Comment: Isn't this a question of the category “this must have been asked before”? https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsequences-and-series%5D+subsequence+to+limsup

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it is, but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n_0=1$ and for $k\geq 1$, define $$n_{k+1}:=\inf\left\{n>n_{k}\mid s_{n_k}-\frac{1}{n_k}\leq x_{n}\leq s_{n_k} \right\}.$$
Then $(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(x_k)$ that converges to $S$.